# MongoDB find by Id in nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My model called **Residence**

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb762" },
    "spaces": [{ 
        "_id": { "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb76f" },
        "name": "Building 2",
        "subSpace": [
            {
                "_id": { "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb771" },
                "name": "Basement"
            }, 
            {
                "_id": { "$oid": "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb770" }, 
                "name": "Floors" // Get only the name by Id
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To find a **spaceName** by Id (OK)

```
exports.getSpaceNameById = (spaceId) => {
    return Residence.find({ 'spaces._id': spaceId }, { _id: 0, spaces: { $elemMatch: { _id: spaceId } } })
}
```

Now I want to have the subSpace name requested by Id.

But my dream would be to have both (query by subSpace Id, for this example : *5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb770*) : **spaceName / subSpaceName** only with 1 request.

Thanks for your help.

---

***UPDATE 1***

I try this method but the response is an empty array

```
exports.getSubSpaceNameById = (spaceId) => {
    return Residence.aggregate([
        { $match: {'spaces.subSpace._id': spaceId}},
        { $project: {
            'spaces.subSpace': { $filter: {
                input: '$spaces.subSpace',
                as: 'mySubSpace',
                cond: { $eq: ['$$mySubSpace._id', spaceId]}
            }},
            _id: 0
        }}
    ])
}
```

Comment: No, as I say in my post update

Comment: To clarify ( [as there is some discussion on this already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390887/2313887) ) the reason your question is closed is not actually a "suggestion" despite the comment currently automatically added. The question is closed because **I know** from many years of experience that this is indeed the answer. If you get an empty result, then you provided incorrect details. The method demonstrated is indeed correct. Please learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

> ```
> find({spaces._id:id})
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you. This query would return the whole document.

By name:
`db.collection.find({"spaces.subSpace.name": "Basement"})`

By _id: `db.collection.find({"spaces.subSpace._id": "YOUR_ID"})`

Comment: Yes I already tried this query but when I have the entire document, how to find the good subSpace name requested ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
   db.testers.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "spaces":{
                $map:{
                    "input":"$spaces",
                    "as":"doc",
                    "in":{
                        $mergeObjects:[
                            "$$doc",
                            {
                                "subSpace":{
                                    $filter:{
                                        "input":"$$doc.subSpace",
                                        "as":"sn",
                                        "cond": {
                                        "$and": [
                                            { "$eq": [ "$$sn._id", "5d88dfe45feb4c06a5cfb770" ] },
                                        ]
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks but this request returns all documents in the collection

Comment: Please share response